# Error in Netbeans & Svn: Pristine text not found

Tags: svn, netbeans

I'm trying to commit some files to my svn repo with netbeans and I always get this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155004: There are unfinished work items in '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ppxtrlgs'; run 'svn cleanup' first.
```

So, when I do svn cleanup, I get this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155032: Pristine text not found
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this "Pristine text not found" 
 when I was trying to SVN "update to head" in Netbeans. 
I am using TortoiseSVN, 
 I go to the Project Folder in Windows, 
right click and select "SVN Update" of TortoiseSVN ,
 then it works, hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution of this problem

- Take a backup of changed files
- Delete the project
- Checkout the same project again.
- Merge the backup file to the new checked out project

Comment: haha simple solution always works. try using 'meld' for the merge.

Comment: Not the elegant solution with a very huge change and so many different change... people said about SmartSVN to solve this issue; Not copy, delete and paste.